# Need my App to take pic or Upload pic and show it in another activity at all time

Tags: android, android-intent

I am totally new to java development. I am working on an App that has a profile page where it contains username, First&lastname, phone# etc(these info are saved by SharedPreference). In the same page i have pic ImageButton when clicked, it takes it to another activity where user can upload pic from gallery or take a pic.

Problem 1- (Camera Activity)I am able to take a pic using  the camera which also is saved in Gallery since i am using the camera app  but it doesn't stay there

```
case R.id.takepic:
            Intent intent = new       Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, cameraData);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent    imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

case cameraData:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras =imageReturnedIntent.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imagepreview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Problem 2: I am not sure how to bring the uploaded pic to another Activity(MainActivity)

I would really appreciate if anyone can tell me how can i have my pic brought back to my MainActivity or have it save so i could use it in any other Activity by calling it.

I have done some searches but it is really confusing for me to understand how saving images and retrieving it works, therefore not able to get it to work. Please HELP. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Click event Just write this code

```
case R.id.iv_attachment_pic:
        CharSequence[] names = { "From Galary", "From Camera" };
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Select an option")
                .setItems(names, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int pos) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (pos == 0) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(
                                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(i, GET_GAL_IMG);
                        } else {
                            Intent i = new Intent(
                                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            startActivityForResult(i, GET_CAM_IMG);
                        }

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                            }
                        }).create().show();
        break;
```

and to get that back to main activity just use onactivity result like this

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    switch (requestCode) {

    case 2:
        if (resultCode == -1) {
            encodedImageString = null;
            Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            bmp_image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            iv_attachment.setImageBitmap(bmp_image);
            if (bmp_image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos)) {
                byte[] image = baos.toByteArray();
                encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(image,
                        Base64.DEFAULT);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Compreesion returned false");
                Log.d("Compress", "Compreesion returned false");
            }
        }

        break;
    case 3:
        if (resultCode == -1) {
            encodedImageString = null;
            bmp_image = null;
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            bmp_image = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            iv_attachment.setImageBitmap(bmp_image);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if (bmp_image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos)) {
                byte[] image = baos.toByteArray();
                encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(image,
                        Base64.DEFAULT);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Compreesion returned false");
                Log.d("Compress", "Compreesion returned false");
            }

        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Here GET_GAL_IMG and GET_CAM_IMG are two variables and iv_attachment is the imageview in your main activity

Comment: Thanks Kartheek for you reply. Really Appreciate it. Just have some issue. I set the 2 Variable GET_GAL_IMG and GET_CAM_IMG as BITMAP. However i am getting error on  startActivityForResult(i, GET_GAL_IMG);.  It shows to be red. Another thing that i am not sure is context. new AlertDialog.Builder(context).it also red. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: i figured out the context which is suppose to be context and the variable for GET_CAM_IMG should be int. However after running the app, and clicking on the button, it force close itself. Any idea

Comment: @Jisbran Ahsan : Context context = this;   and keep 1 for GET_GAL_IMG and 2 for GET_CAM_IMG i.e.     ((int GET_CAM_IMG =2))

Comment: Thank you so much. I am able to get the camera and gallery to appear as a Dialog and able to take pic and upload.However when it returns, the upload/taken pic doesn't show in my ImageButton even though i have mentioned it setImageBitmap.